# WiFiKill is giving pcap_loop failed

Tags: android, root, android-wifi, packet-sniffers

WiFi Kill for Android on MIUI 9 based on Nougat throws an error after scanning for networks i.e. pcap_loop failed.

[image: Error Screenshot]

What is causing this? How to fix it?

Answer (score -1):

Install SELinux mode changer apk give root permission, you will see 2 options permissive and enforcing, select permissive and reboot your device, (just give it a try, it might not work on every device)